# Android studio 3.6 cannot resolve symbol generated by view binding

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.6, android-viewbinding

I am implementing [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and I have problem with Cannot resolve some symbols. For some Views the IDE writes to me: `Cannot resolve symbol`.

Activity: `ActivityMain`

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding viewBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set activity layout.
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = viewBinding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        new AdAdaptiveKt(this, viewBinding.adViewContainer); //<<== Cannot resolve symbol viewBinding.adViewContainer

    }


}
```

Layout `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    ...

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/adViewContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />
     ...
</FrameLayout>
```

When I find the generated file:
`/home/XXX/android-projects/XXX/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/out/XX/XXX/XXX/databinding/ActivityMainBinding.java`:

```
public final class ActivityMainBinding implements ViewBinding {

    ...

  @NonNull
  public final FrameLayout adViewContainer;

   ...
}
```

**All Views are generated correctly. Build is OK and I can run project in a real device. But Android Studio still writes me: `Cannot resolve symbol`.**

Android studio 3.6.3,
Android gradle plugin 3.6.3,
Gradle: tested: 5.6.4 - 6.3

I tried:

- clean project, rebuild,
- Invalidate caches and restart,
- Import project
- Delete `.idea` and `.gradle` project directories
- Delete directory `/home/XXX/.gradle` and open project
- Open project in Android Studio 4.0-beta1 and 4.1-canary2

**Problem solved**
I had comment (`<!--&&-->`) in layout and `viewBinding` does not work properly. I do not why? Could anybody verify it?